# How to get any feedback from Nexcloud Android app download errors?

Tags: applications

I installed the [Nextcloud Android App](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=nextcloud&c=apps&hl=en&gl=US) and configured my Provider Login successfully. My files are listed, but no download works (in 100% of a gazillion attempts). There's no feedback from the app, permissions for notification has been granted as well as all other permissions. No entries in the activity log of the app.

An app that doesn't give feedback on errors has such a low UX that it comes close to unusability. However there're no alternative afaik. Is there any way I can get any feedback why the downloads fail?

experienced with 3.25.0 on Android 11

Comment: Usually app errors should be visible an `adb logcat` (requires developer options, enabled, adb enabled, phone connected to a PC/MAC e.g. via USB, minimal adb or Android SDK installed on PC side). Do you use "unusual" folder names as mentioned in this issue? https://github.com/nextcloud/android/issues/11720

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the hint, no there're unusual folder names in my account the sense of the issue. I guess, I'll compare apps of other cloud storage solutions and consider a switch.